# sentencia if no funciona al tipear numeros mayores a 3

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Tengo un incoveniente en js, el problema se genera cuando tipeo un numero mayor a 2 en "_vacDias" la funcion no se ejecuta, pero si tipeo 1 o 2 funciona correctamente, al parecer el problama esta en el if, pero no logro dar con la solucion

```js
    function CalculoDias(obj){
      var idObj = obj.id; // =vacDias.0
      var numAr = idObj.split("."); 
      var diasLabTotal = document.getElementById("_diasMes."+numAr[1]+''); // =28
      if (obj.value>0 && diasLabTotal.value >=obj.value) {
        //var idDiasLab = "_diasLaborados."+numAr[1]+'';
        var diasLab = document.getElementById("_diasLaborados."+numAr[1]+'');// = 28 
        var vacDias = obj.value;
        diasLab.value = (parseInt(diasLabTotal.value) - parseInt(obj.value));
      }else{
        alert(diasLabTotal.value+'^^4^^'+obj.value);
      }
      
      //alert(obj.value +'------'+ vacDias +"**"+ diasLab.value);      
    }
```

```html
<tr >
              <td><input type="hidden" value="28" id="_diasMes.0">
              <input type="number" max="28" min="0" readonly="" name="_diasLaborados[]" id="_diasLaborados.0" style="max-width: 50px;" value="28"></td>
              
              <td><input type="text" id="_vacDias.0" onkeyup="CalculoDias(this);" name="_vacDias[]" style="width: 60px;"></td></tr>
```

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no estás transformando a números en la comparación `if (obj.value>0 && diasLabTotal.value >= obj.value)` por lo que está haciendo la comparación como `strings`.

Con `if (parseInt(obj.value)>0 && parseInt(diasLabTotal.value) >= parseInt(obj.value))` funcionará sin problemas (como estás haciendo al asignar `diasLab.value`)

```js
function CalculoDias(obj){
      var idObj = obj.id; // =vacDias.0
      var numAr = idObj.split("."); 
      var diasLabTotal = document.getElementById("_diasMes."+numAr[1]+''); // =28
      if (parseInt(obj.value)>0 && parseInt(diasLabTotal.value) >= parseInt(obj.value)) {
        var diasLab = document.getElementById("_diasLaborados."+numAr[1]+'');// = 28 
        var vacDias = obj.value;
        diasLab.value = (parseInt(diasLabTotal.value) - parseInt(obj.value));
      }else{
        alert(diasLabTotal.value+'^^4^^'+obj.value);
      }    
    }
```

```html
<tr >
  <td>
    <input type="hidden" value="28" id="_diasMes.0">
    <input type="number" max="28" min="0" readonly="" name="_diasLaborados[]" id="_diasLaborados.0" style="max-width: 50px;" value="28">
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="text" id="_vacDias.0" onkeyup="CalculoDias(this);" name="_vacDias[]" style="width: 60px;">
  </td>
</tr>
```